# Identify the music on Australian advertisement for Sidchrome spanners

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music, instrumental

Back in the 1980s or 90s, there was an advertisement on Australian TV for Sidchrome spanners. It showed a collection of spanners being made, starting with red hot metal being stamped out, then cleaned up, filed down, washed, and finally presented. At the end a voiceover said in a broad Australian accent "Sidchrome. Ya canna hand a man a grander spanner."

Behind all this there was quite a cheerful, flowing piece of classical music. I have never heard it anywhere else and I have no idea what it's called or who wrote it. Does anyone else remember this ad and know what the music was?

I went looking on youtube and found a couple of old Sidchrome ads and lot of Australian ads from the period, but not this one. I will update if I can find a clip.

Update: I wrote down the first couple of bars in musical notation. Take this with a grain of salt, because I can't read or write music; I sounded it out on a musical score site and took a screenshot. I couldn't make the tempo sound quite right, but I think the notes are correct relative to each other. I'll add more when I get a chance.
[image: First two bars]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it on youtube by accident. Not the advertisement, but the actual piece.

It's Bach's Violin Concerto in A Minor, BWV 1041. [Here's a recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uInUkHElPYM), with the musical score scrolling as it goes so you can see that my version was far from perfect.

It's a good piece. Go listen even if you never saw the ad.